# java8 stream toArray question - Why i don't need specify array size here for int[][]::new?

Tags: java, java-stream

Using below code , I could copy 2 dimensional array, but why i don't need
specify array size here for int[][]::new?

```
int[][]source= {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0}};

int[][] destination=Arrays.stream(source)
                    .map(a ->  Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length))
                    .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: when you return an array from a function you also don't have to specify the size

Answer (score 5):

Because what you provide is not an array, but a reference to the method to construct the array. The `toArray` implementation will provided the size to call the constructor.

Comment: toArray implementation will only provide one param value, but here you need two value for 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @stewchicken: no, because the inner arrays will already be created by then. Think of the the `int[][]` created using this parameter as just a 1-dimensional array where the element type happens to be another 1-dimensional array `int[]`. Basically that line will effectively do the equivalent of `new int[someSize][]`.

Comment: Areus and Joachim, thanks for your quick explanation!